# Application hosted in IIS stopping after the event id 12 and 9009

Tags: .net, iis, iis-10, event-viewer

I have hosted multiple applications in IIS and all applications are stopping at the same time. When I checked the event viewer, I can see only the logs for event id 12 and 9009 around that time. This happened multiple times a day and all these times the event logs entered for these two event Ids.

Please see the description for the event logs:

Event Id 12:

> Process SysWOW64\powercfg.exe reset policy scheme from {.........} to {...........}

Event Id 9009:

> The Application Host Helper Service encountered an error trying to delete the history directory '~\inetpub\history\CFGHISTORY_0000000823'. The directory will be skipped and ignored. Note that the directory may still get deleted in the future if the service restarts.

I am not able to find any other logs related to IIS or worker process and totally blind on how to debug this issue.

IIS version we are using is 10.0 and the Windows edition is Windows Server 2016 Standard.

Comment: Can you rebuild the server and point your domain or load balancer at the new IP address?

Comment: Since high reliability is important for your applications, do you have a load balancer and a farm of web servers? In other words, do you have any architecture in place to reduce downtime?

Comment: @halfer Could you please give me an insight into why these warnings are showing in event viewer and stopping our application frequently. I don't have much idea about these events and am trying to figure out the root cause.And we dont have a load balancer for our application.If we have one,how it connected to these events?

Comment: I don't have any knowledge of Windows hosting, sorry. If you can't rebuild the server then searching for the errors in a search engine may give you some clues.

Comment: @KesiyaAbraham, Are you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Event ID 9009 is logged when the Application Host Helper Service encountered an error trying to delete the history directory.
To resolve this issue you need to restart the AppHostSvc.

You could follow below steps to restart AppHostSvc using command prompt:
Run command prompt as administrator.
Type command `net stop apphostsvc`
Type command `net start apphostsvc`

for event id 12 One or more hash tables or Group.lst files are corrupt or missing; the server failed to add information for a posting.

Comment: This is helpful. How these events are affecting our application pools/worker process?

Comment: The Application Host Helper Service (AppHostSvc) provides administrative services for IIS, for example configuration history and Application Pool account mapping. If this service is stopped, the IIS configuration history feature will not work, and you will be unable to use Application Pool-specific access control entries to lock down files or directories.

Comment: you can refer this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/install/installing-iis-7/applicationhost-helper-service) for more detail about ApplicationHost Helper Service.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I am wondering how these two events are related. i.e, the Event Id 12 always followed by event id 9009.